# Active Directory Login Problem

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have 2 users in my AD installation with the same CN

```
   CN=jack,CN=Users,DC=xyz,DC=com and 
   CN=jack,OU=abc,DC=xyz,DC=com
```

When I try to authenticate to the AD Server using the Apache Directory Studio client and give the following credentials

```
User: jack
Password: <password>
```

the authentication fails. The following credentials work

```
User: CN=jack,CN=Users,DC=xyz,DC=com
Passwprd: <password>
```

When I have only a single user `CN=tom,DC=xyz,DC=com` with a given CN

I am able to login with

```
User: tom
Password: <password>
```

without having to specify the entire DN (`CN=tom,DC=xyz,DC=com`) .

I need to write a module to authenticate users against an AD installation. I have with me only the usernames and passwords and not the fully qualified BASE DNs. I cannot bind to the AD server to be able to use filters like `(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=jack))`. How do I do this as the problem it seems happens when there are more than one user with the same CN ?

**EDIT**: Can I configure the AD server to bind against mail address/sAMAccountName of the users instead of CN ? This would solve my problem as these are unique while CN's are not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the attribute I was looking for --> `userPrincipalName` (UPN) . This has a unique value in Active Directory and can be supplied as the user name while attempting to authenticate. So now I need a list of UPNs and the corresponding passwords for login.

Check [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739093%28WS.10%29.aspx) too.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of login are you doing in your 'module'?  If you cannot bind and do an ldap query, then what interface are you logging in with?  You need to configure whatever that is to use sAMAccountName as that is the only guarenteed unique per domain name.  Of course if you have more than one domain in the forest then they only have to be unique per domain, so that may not work so well.

If you are only able to do an LDAP bind as the user, and not query.  Perhaps you could try to connect as sAMAccountname=jack as you pass credentails.